Правильно ли стоит запятая с вводным словом "предположительно"?
Правильно ли я понимаю, что здесь обособленный оборот с вводным словом в начале оборота?
В ходе осмотра квартиры найдено три мелких пакета, предположительно с порошком.

Правильно:
В ходе осмотра квартиры найдено три мелких пакЕта, предположительно с порошкОм.
Пояснение

Да, здесь обособленный оборот с вводным словом в начале оборота.

Справочник
 ПРЕДПОЛОЖИТЕЛЬНО, вводное слово
 То же, что «вероятно, возможно, скорее всего». 


Исходное предложение: В ходе осмотра квартиры найдено три мелких пакЕта, с порошкОм.

Оборот обособляется со значением уточнения (стилевая особенность текста), а вводное слово дополняет семантику оборота.
